# make targets depend on variables

Tags: variables, makefile

I want (GNU) `make` to rebuild when variables change. How can I achieve this?

For example,

```
$ make project
[...]
$ make project
make: `project' is up to date.
```

...like it should, but then I'd prefer

```
$ make project IMPORTANTVARIABLE=foobar
make: `project' is up to date.
```

to rebuild some or all of `project`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use empty files to record the last value of your variable by using something like this:

```
someTarget: IMPORTANTVARIABLE.$(IMPORTANTVARIABLE)
    @echo Remaking $@ because IMPORTANTVARIABLE has changed
    touch $@

IMPORTANTVARIABLE.$(IMPORTANTVARIABLE):
    @rm -f IMPORTANTVARIABLE.*
    touch $@
```

After your `make` run, there will be an empty file in your directory whose name starts with `IMPORTANTVARIABLE.` and has the value of your variable appended. This basically contains the information about what the last value of the variable `IMPORTANTVARIABLE` was.

You can add more variables with this approach and make it more sophisticated using pattern rules -- but this example gives you the gist of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for variables with spaces in their values. Famous CFLAGS (space-separated compiler flags) is the case. Also, '/' in values will cause problems.

Answer (score 12):

Make wasn't designed to refer to variable content but Reinier's approach shows us the workaround. Unfortunately, using variable value as a file name is both insecure and error-prone. Hopefully, Unix tools can help us to properly encode the value. So

```
IMPORTANTVARIABLE = a trouble

# GUARD is a function which calculates md5 sum for its
# argument variable name. Note, that both cut and md5sum are
# members of coreutils package so they should be available on
# nearly all systems.
GUARD = $(1)_GUARD_$(shell echo $($(1)) | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)

foo: bar $(call GUARD,IMPORTANTVARIABLE)
    @echo "Rebuilding foo with $(IMPORTANTVARIABLE)"
    @touch $@

$(call GUARD,IMPORTANTVARIABLE):
    rm -rf IMPORTANTVARIABLE*
    touch $@
```

Here you virtually depend your target on a special file named `$(NAME)_GUARD_$(VALUEMD5)` which is safe to refer to and has (almost) 1-to-1 correspondence with variable's value. Note that `call` and `shell` are GNU Make extensions.

Comment: as cool solution as this is - it doesnt work when a variable is assigned during makefile evaluation. only for the ones that get passed directly from outer call

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use `ifdef` or `ifeq` depending on what the final goal is. See the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html) for examples.

Comment: Thank you Thor! For posterity: `ifdef` & `ifeq` are similar to the `C` preprocessor (but for make), a block of lines in the makefile is made active or inactive depending on a condition. - Accepting the other answer beacuse I'll go for Reinier's solution, without much reason.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late with an answer, but here is another way of doing such a dependency with [Make conditional syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) (works on GNU Make 4.1, GNU bash, Bash on Ubuntu on Windows version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)):

```
1 ifneq ($(shell cat config.sig 2>/dev/null),prefix $(CONFIG))
2 .PHONY: config.sig
3 config.sig:
4   @(echo 'prefix $(CONFIG)' >config.sig &)
5 endif
```

In the above sample we track the `$(CONFIG)` variable, writing it's value down to a signature file, by means of the self-titled target which is generated under condition when the signature file's record value is different with that of `$(CONFIG)` variable. Please, note the *prefix* on lines 1 and 4: it is needed to distinct the case, when signature file doesn't exist yet.

Of course, consumer targets specify `config.sig` as a prerequisite.

Comment: If a target has a phony prerequisite (like `config.sig` in your case) — this target will be rebuild on every request for it.

Comment: Yea but this entire target is only conditionally defined if config.sig is different from CONFIG, which means that it will not have a valid rule when its the same, meaning it won't re-generate.